# Running iperf3 with crypto/ssh and golang

Tags: go, performance-testing, channel, iperf3

### Goal

Use Golang's crypto/ssh to run iperf3 on two VMs to measure throughput.

### The manual process

Here is a description of the manual process that works. I am trying to do the same thing in golang.

#### Manual Approach: From a jumpbox, connect to VM1 and run iperf as `server`

```
# Login to VM1
ssh testadmin@168.61.222.12
# Run iperf server on VM1
iperf3 -s -p 5001
```

[image]

You can see from the image above that the server is sitting there listening. The same command hangs the golang code as explained below.

#### Manual Approach: From a jumpbox, connect to VM2 and run iperf as `client`

```
# Login to VM2
ssh testadmin@23.101.124.159

# Run client tests on VM2
iperf3 -c 168.61.222.12 -p 5001 -i 1 -t 3
```

All of it works great from the command line. Below is an explanation on using Golang but the code hangs.

### Problem: The golang code hangs

The golang code hangs on the line below. See the function:

```
putVM1IntoServerMode()
```

The code  hangs on:

```
putVM1IntoServerMode() {}
    # Code hangs here
    out, err := 
      VMConnectServer.hostSession.CombinedOutput(VMConnectServer.commands[0])
      ...
}
```

That is kind of expected because of what you see in the manual process:

[image]

### Main Code

```
type VMCONNECT struct {
    hostConnection *ssh.Client
    hostSession    *ssh.Session
    user           string
    hostPort       string
    commands       []string
    password       string
}

var VMConnectServer = VMCONNECT{
    nil,
    nil,
    "testadmin",
    "169.61.222.12:22",
    []string{"iperf3 -s -p 5001"},
    "????",
}
/*************************************
Logic
  connect to server
  put vm into server mode
  connect to client
  run iperf3 tests
  close client
  close server
**************************************/

func main() {

    connectToServer()
    putVM1IntoServerMode()
    // other code ommitted for brevity
}    

# This works fine, no issues
func connectToServer() {
    var err error
    VMConnectServer.hostConnection, VMConnectServer.hostSession, err = connectToHost(VMConnectServer.user, VMConnectServer.hostPort)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

# Code hangs here
func putVM1IntoServerMode() {
    # Code hangs here
    out, err := VMConnectServer.hostSession.CombinedOutput(VMConnectServer.commands[0])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

### How to solve

Do I run code async using a channel?
What is the best way to solve this issue?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

## Success!

When running on the server side of iperf, it is very tricky.

```
func runIperfTestsFromVM2() string {
    fmt.Println(VMConnectClient.commands[0])
    out, err := VMConnectClient.hostSession.CombinedOutput("sh -c 'nohup iperf3 -s -p 5001 > /dev/null 2>&1 &'")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))
    return string(out)
}
```